# Plucker coordinates of some collection of lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I know that the set of all lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is given by
$$p_{0,1}p_{2,3}-p_{0,2}p_{1,3}+p_{0,3}p_{1,2}=0  \ \ \ (*)$$
where $(p_{0,1}, p_{0,2}, p_{0,3}, \cdots, p_{2,3})$ is the Plucker coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^5$.

How do you get the Plucker coordinates of some subset of lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$? For example let's consider the set of lines through $P \in \mathbb{P}^3$.

I know that the set of lines through $P$ can be identified with $\mathbb{P}^2$, and according to the ***table A.1: Varieties of degree 1 in projective space*** here (http://robotics.technion.ac.il/people/alon/Appendix%20A.htm), I must find two linear equations in terms of $p_{ij}$ that every element in the set satisfies. We are given the (homogeneous) coordinates of $P$, say $(a, b, c, d)$, but I can't think of the way to get the two more linear equations.

Comment: Hint: if a point $a$ is on a line $\overline{bc}$, then the matrix with rows $a$, $b$, and $c$ is of rank $2$. Do you see where to go from here?

Comment: @KReiser Okay I see what you are trying to do, but I'm not sure about the linear algebra part. What is the equivalent condition to such matrix have rank less than 3? Is it enough to say the determinant of $3\times 3$ submatrices all euqals to 0? (there are 4 of them given by columns of the $3\times 4$ matrix; (1,2,3), (1, 2, 4) ,(1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)). Combined with the condition that two rows are independent (the rows from vectors spanning the line), the $3 \times 4$ will have rank exactly $2$?

Comment: Yes, that's the right track - now cofactor expand along the row with $a$. Do the $2\times 2$ minors look familiar? (They should!)

Comment: @ KReiser I got 4 more linear equations and indeed if I pair them and solve, I end up with the same equation so I only need two of them.  So total 3 equations are needed to get the set. Thanks for your instruction, it was very helpful!

Comment: Great, I'm glad you figured it out. Please consider writing this up in an answer to your own question - I'm sure others who come across this question in the future will appreciate it.

Comment: I can do write the solution later thanks